# WPF Checkbox content not correct

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My problem is my checkbox content doesnt display underscores or the `&` symbol. I've read about the `RecognizeAccessKey` attribute, but i can't get it working. My listbox looks like this:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="False">
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Item}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                          Width="149"
                          MinWidth="149" />
            </ContentPresenter>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Can anybody tell me how to get this fixed, so my Checkbox's content will display underscores and `&` symbols?

thank you very much!

Comment: What does it display in place of the underscore and ampersand?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `TextBlock` as `CheckBox.Content`, instead of binding it directly, and bind its `Text` property

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Width="149" MinWidth="149">
   <CheckBox.Content>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item}"/>
   </CheckBox.Content>
</CheckBox>
```

By default `CheckBox` will wrap `TextBlock` in `AccessText` when it displays `Content`