# C# CheckBox Content correct formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, formatting

I have a C# WPF application, where I create CheckBoxes dynamically,
and their properties are set
through a foreach loop through a MyList, made of objects, as I need to contain different types of data.
At index 1, the lists contain the Name I want to use as the CheckBox.Content.

My loop looks like:

```
int i = 1;
foreach (List<Object> o in MyList)
{
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
cb.Name = o[1].ToString() + i.ToString();
cb.Content = string.Format("  " + o[1].ToString());
// then I add the CheckBox to a StackPanel
checkBoxesStackPanel.Children.Add(cb);
i++;
}
```

The issue I face is that CheckBox.Content does not format correctly the names from the lists.
I cannot control the characters of the list, as they are created by specific users groups with
different requirements.

Example:
if I have an element in the list like "1234_ABC_123456_AB_12"
it is shown in the WPF as something similar to "1234ABC_123456_AB_12".

How do I format correctly the cb.Content so the CheckBoxes.Content will display correctly in my WPF app?

I looked at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/checkbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

but could not find an example to address this issue.

Initially, I had this solution in WindowsForms, and the CheckBoxes text was displaying correctly.
Now I'm migrating the solution to WPF and I need to fix this last small (but annoying) issue.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310482/wpf-checkbox-content-not-correct

Comment: "Now I'm migrating the solution to WPF" - you will benefit a lot from reading   http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/ articles

Answer (score -1):

You could try to see if the following method suits you.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="sp">
        
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    List<string> MyList;
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      MyList = new List<string>();
      for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
      {
        MyList.Add( $"1234_ABC_123456_AB_1{ i }");
      }
      int n = 1;
      foreach (var item in MyList)
      {
        if (n < MyList.Count)
        {
          CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
          cb.Name = "cb" + n;
          cb.Content = MyList[n].ToString();
          sp.Children.Add(cb);
        }
        n++;
      }
    }
  }
```

[The result picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWHtf.png)